# does as3xls library handles hyperlink in excel file..?

Tags: actionscript-3, excel, data-binding, datagrid, flex4

Is "as3xls library" capable of handling a hyper link in excel file, is there any other library which i can use for importing data from .xlsx file. as3xls is limited to .xls only.

Comment: Why don't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: as3xls is useful for reading simple, one sheet .xls. Anything else, you need to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.xlsx files are basically just XML files that are mapped to each other and zipped up into a zip archive.  The way I have dealt with them is to use something like [nochump](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15)'s zip library to unpack them, and then traverse the contained XML yourself.  Other than that, I don't know of any libraries set up to deal with xlsx files directly (you are correct that as3xls only deals with the older, more difficult binary xls format).  You may find some resources such as the [OOXML spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) helpful as well.

Comment: Yup also Microsoft has a SDK XML comparison tool that makes understanding the ***x office formats easier.  You may also want to consider using the open document format instead as it is from what I read slightly simpler.  I've written a custom XLSX exporter using the tools mentioned and by simply piecing apart a "template" blank xlsx file then creating classes that would generate xml strings for each of the files in the zip, the opposite could certainly be done.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: thanks waxspin. but i found something interesting on internet where we can use apache poi library to read data from .xlxs file and about the hiper link, i will try your technique. i knew that excel files are xml files but never thought of using them in this useful way, thanks for your input...

Comment: Yeah, I imagine poi would work too -- I think the main issue is whether you want to do it server side or client side :)  Good luck!